# Nextflow Channel create with condition

Tags: nextflow

```
[Kasumi_H3K36, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/d0/3db2bde9eb1bdb0578073fb128bc4c/Kasumi_H3K36.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_JMJD1C, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/b1/dffe2120acda5b05860e1a3bb0c1bf/Kasumi_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_NCOR1, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/9f/7c3680a1ff0ae0a5a27f42e1a27225/Kasumi_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_IgG, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/21/1038cd4ecbc5b3f88da23ad1ee3147/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_H4K5, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/3d/7b5239ab9dc83b00f992fea8926630/Kasumi_H4K5.no0.bedgraph]
```

This is one of my channel view. I am trying to make a new control channel when the first and second ID are same, and the rest as sample channel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using the [branch](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#branch) operator. I made some assumptions about what the fields should be named, but hopefully the pattern is close to what you're looking for:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

Channel
    .of(
        ['Kasumi_H3K36', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/d0/3db2bde9eb1bdb0578073fb128bc4c/Kasumi_H3K36.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_JMJD1C', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/b1/dffe2120acda5b05860e1a3bb0c1bf/Kasumi_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_NCOR1', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/9f/7c3680a1ff0ae0a5a27f42e1a27225/Kasumi_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_IgG', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/21/1038cd4ecbc5b3f88da23ad1ee3147/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_H4K5', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/3d/7b5239ab9dc83b00f992fea8926630/Kasumi_H4K5.no0.bedgraph')],
    ) \
    .branch { sample1, sample2, bedgraph ->
        controls: sample1 == sample2
            return tuple( sample1, sample2, bedgraph )
        others: true
            return tuple( sample1, sample2, bedgraph )
    } \
    .set { inputs } 

inputs.controls.view { "controls: $it" } 
inputs.others.view { "others: $it" }
```

Results:

```
others: [Kasumi_H3K36, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/d0/3db2bde9eb1bdb0578073fb128bc4c/Kasumi_H3K36.no0.bedgraph]
controls: [Kasumi_IgG, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/21/1038cd4ecbc5b3f88da23ad1ee3147/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
others: [Kasumi_JMJD1C, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/b1/dffe2120acda5b05860e1a3bb0c1bf/Kasumi_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph]
others: [Kasumi_NCOR1, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/9f/7c3680a1ff0ae0a5a27f42e1a27225/Kasumi_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph]
others: [Kasumi_H4K5, Kasumi_IgG, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/3d/7b5239ab9dc83b00f992fea8926630/Kasumi_H4K5.no0.bedgraph]
```

---

Update from comments:

```
Channel
    .of(
        ['Kasumi_H3K36', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/path/to/Kasumi_H3K36.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_JMJD1C', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/path/to/Kasumi_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_NCOR1', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/path/to/Kasumi_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_IgG', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/path/to/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['Kasumi_H4K5', 'Kasumi_IgG', file('/path/to/Kasumi_H4K5.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['NB4_H3K36', 'NB4_IgG', file('/path/to/NB4_H3K36.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['NB4_JMJD1C', 'NB4_IgG', file('/path/to/NB4_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['NB4_NCOR1', 'NB4_IgG', file('/path/to/NB4_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['NB4_IgG', 'NB4_IgG', file('/path/to/NB4_IgG.no0.bedgraph')],
        ['NB4_H4K5', 'NB4_IgG', file('/path/to/NB4_H4K5.no0.bedgraph')],
    ) \
    .branch { test_sample, control_sample, bedgraph ->
        control_samples: test_sample == control_sample
            return tuple( control_sample, tuple( test_sample, bedgraph ) )
        test_samples: true
            return tuple( control_sample, tuple( test_sample, bedgraph ) )
    } \
    .set { inputs }

inputs.test_samples
    .combine( inputs.control_samples, by: 0 ) \
    .map { group, test_tuple, control_tuple ->
        tuple( *test_tuple, *control_tuple )
    } \
    .view()
```

Results:

```
[Kasumi_H3K36, /path/to/Kasumi_H3K36.no0.bedgraph, Kasumi_IgG, /path/to/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_JMJD1C, /path/to/Kasumi_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph, Kasumi_IgG, /path/to/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_NCOR1, /path/to/Kasumi_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph, Kasumi_IgG, /path/to/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[Kasumi_H4K5, /path/to/Kasumi_H4K5.no0.bedgraph, Kasumi_IgG, /path/to/Kasumi_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[NB4_H3K36, /path/to/NB4_H3K36.no0.bedgraph, NB4_IgG, /path/to/NB4_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[NB4_JMJD1C, /path/to/NB4_JMJD1C.no0.bedgraph, NB4_IgG, /path/to/NB4_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[NB4_NCOR1, /path/to/NB4_NCOR1.no0.bedgraph, NB4_IgG, /path/to/NB4_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
[NB4_H4K5, /path/to/NB4_H4K5.no0.bedgraph, NB4_IgG, /path/to/NB4_IgG.no0.bedgraph]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Today I create a new conda environment to do my pipeline. The code went through yesterday using base environmrnt, but there is error today using new environment.
error:[warm up] executor > local
ERROR ~ No signature of method: groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowQueue.branch() is applicable for argument types: (_nf_script_a5c6c25c$_run_closure11) values: [_nf_script_a5c6c25c$_run_closure11@20f6f88c]
Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), mean(), print(), any(), bind(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: @Shikan: no worries, what version of Nextflow are you using? Branch needs `19.08.0-edge` or later.

Comment: Nextflow version is 19.01.0

Comment: @Shikan: yeah, you'll need a newer version to use the branch operator. Try `nextflow self-update`

Comment: Sorry I have more questions. I am actually using nextflow to write a pipeline. I'm applying SEACR to my pipeline. Have you seen this error?  Error in read.table(argsL$exp) : no lines available in input
Execution halted

Comment: @Shikan: I think that looks like an issue with an R command used by SEACR. Check that your input file is being localized correctly in the process workdir and that it isn't empty. 'No lines available' suggests the file is being localized but it's just an empty file. HTH.

Comment: I did check there are files and they are not empty

Comment: I looked at bedgraph files. The forth column are all zeros. I think that's probably causing the problem

Comment: I'm using these inputs (change to return only two elements, sample_id and bedgraph)
    "input:
    set val(sample_id), file(bed_samples) from samples_controls_ch.samples
    set val(sample_id_control), file(bed_controls) from samples_controls_ch.controls"
however, when I run the script "bash SEACR_1.3.sh ${bed_samples} ${bed_controls} non stringent ${sample_id}", it only runs one sample

Comment: If your 'controls' channel should be a value channel, you can just call 'collect', i.e. `set val(sample_id_control), file(bed_controls) from samples_controls_ch.controls.collect()`. See [Understand how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work).

Comment: In example above, I have Kasumi sample compare with Kasumi control. If I have more than one set of comparison. like another group NB4 sample with NB4 control. How do I set up the correct input, so the comparison matching each other?

Comment: If I have two inputs with different number of files, how do I input those files. It gave me error (unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"')

Comment: @Shikan: I updated my answer with what _I think_ you're looking for in your first question. Sorry I don't understand your second one. You may like to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question and add some more details.