# Nextflow deepTools fingerprint

Tags: nextflow

I am trying to use nextflow pipeline to do a fringerprint(bamCoverage) from deeptool. When I input the bam files and run the script. it says I don't have index files. error: [E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for 'Kasumi_NCOR1.genome.sorted.bam'
[E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for 'Kasumi_NCOR1.genome.sorted.bam'
'Kasumi_NCOR1.genome.sorted.bam' does not appear to have an index. You MUST index the file first!

```
process fingerprint_cov {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/fingerprint_cov", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    set val(sample_id), file(samples) from sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.samples
    set val(sample_id_c), file(controls) from sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.controls

    output:
    set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.cov.bedgraph") into sample_cov_ch
    set val(sample_id_c), file("${sample_id_c}.cov.bedgraph") into control_cov_ch

    script:
    """

    bamCoverage -b ${samples} -o ${sample_id}.cov.bedgraph -of bedgraph -bs 1000 -p 10
    bamCoverage -b ${controls} -o ${sample_id_c}.cov.bedgraph -of bedgraph -bs 1000 -p 10

    """
}
```

sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.samples has all the sample bam files, and sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.control has the control bam files. How do I input the bam.bai files? I have also seen that output bam and bam.bai to a channel, but how to process this steps?

This is my sample input. but when I run the process it only runs one sample

```
[Kasumi_H3K36, [/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/0c/24e138a92a1eb0d906e1e9fad9ba4b/Kasumi_H3K36.genome.sorted.bam, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/0c/24e138a92a1eb0d906e1e9fad9ba4b/Kasumi_H3K36.genome.sorted.bam.bai]]
[Kasumi_H4K5, [/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/7e/a740e11ce39f2a310b749603c785a4/Kasumi_H4K5.genome.sorted.bam, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/7e/a740e11ce39f2a310b749603c785a4/Kasumi_H4K5.genome.sorted.bam.bai]]
[Kasumi_NCOR1, [/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/b8/e91ff7c7aea0fa3a0814530ab07972/Kasumi_NCOR1.genome.sorted.bam, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/b8/e91ff7c7aea0fa3a0814530ab07972/Kasumi_NCOR1.genome.sorted.bam.bai]]
[Kasumi_JMJD1C, [/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/49/99ebe402d2b1953a95968525e258f6/Kasumi_JMJD1C.genome.sorted.bam, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/49/99ebe402d2b1953a95968525e258f6/Kasumi_JMJD1C.genome.sorted.bam.bai]]
```

Here is the control input

```
[Kasumi_IgG, [/mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/0e/1cd7aefd90105205e58fb6ef912aa4/Kasumi_IgG.genome.sorted.bam, /mnt/Data/cut_and_tag/work/0e/1cd7aefd90105205e58fb6ef912aa4/Kasumi_IgG.genome.sorted.bam.bai]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to index your BAM files first if the index (.bai) files don't already exist. You can use `samtools index <bam>` for this.

Then all you would need to do is input these into your process somehow. Rather than having a separate variable in each of your input sets/tuples, what I find works quite nicely is grouping the BAM files and their indexes in a tuple of the form: `tuple( bam, bai )`

Then your process might look like:

```
process fingerprint_cov {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/fingerprint_cov", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    set val(test_sample_id), file(indexed_test_bam) from sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.samples
    set val(control_sample_id), file(indexed_control_bam) from sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.controls

    output:
    set val(test_sample_id), file("${test_sample_id}.cov.bedgraph") into sample_cov_ch
    set val(control_sample_id), file("${control_sample_id}.cov.bedgraph") into control_cov_ch

    script:
    def test_bam = indexed_test_bam.first()
    def control_bam = indexed_control_bam.first()

    """
    bamCoverage -b "${test_bam}" -o "${sample_id}.cov.bedgraph" -of bedgraph -bs 1000 -p 10
    bamCoverage -b "${control_bam}" -o "${sample_id_c}.cov.bedgraph" -of bedgraph -bs 1000 -p 10
    """
}
```

Comment: Only one of my samples went through. Why is that happened?

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with multiple input channels. Please see: [Understand how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work). You may also want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65429377/edit) your question to include a [view()](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#view) of your input channels.

Comment: the script you advise is working, but only one of the sample went through. I edited the question and provided the sample input channel view

Comment: Sorry @Shikan, can I just check - is that the output of `sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.samples.view()`? What does your other input channel look like? I.e. what's the output of `sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.controls.view()`? If you could clarify that would be great - thanks!

Comment: yes that is the output of sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.samples.view(). I have added the controls.view()

Comment: Thanks @Shikan, please see: [Understand how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work). This is the relevant bit: "When two or more channels are declared as process inputs, the process stops until there’s a complete input configuration ie. it receives an input value from all the channels declared as input." This is the expected behavior when both of your input channels are [queue channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel).

Comment: To get the behavior you want you can just call [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) on your 'controls' channel. I.e. `... from sorted_bam_sample_control_ch.controls.collect()`. You mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385125/nextflow-channel-create-with-condition) that you have other sample groups like 'NB4' that need to go through too but I couldn't seem them in your channel views above. Is that still the case?

Comment: It is a different case. Last one was using sample to compare to the control. This time is two process. I did solve this by splitting into two processes. Thank you!